# Case not evaluating correctly sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case-when

I have a *case when* statement in a extract query which doesn't seem to be returning what i'm expecting

```
DECLARE @Val1 int, @Val2 int,@Val3 int, @Val4 int, @Val5 int

SELECT  @Val1 = 5 , @Val2= 2,@Val3= 200000, @Val5  = 2,@Val4 = 2014
SELECT  @Val1 , @Val2,@Val3, @Val4, @Val5   

SELECT CASE

        WHEN  @Val1 = 5 AND @Val2  IN(1,2) AND @Val3 = 200000 AND @Val4 IS NULL  THEN 'ReturnValue1'
        WHEN  @Val1 = 5 AND @Val2  IN(1,2) AND @Val3 = 200000 AND @Val4 IS NOT NULL THEN 'ReturnValue2'
        WHEN  @Val1 = 5 AND @Val2  = 2 AND @Val3 = 200000  AND @Val5 = 2 AND @Val4 IS NOT NULL THEN 'ReturnValue3'
        ELSE NULL
    END [TestingValue]
```

I'm expecting the value to be ***ReturnValue3*** however it appears to be ignoring this whole line for some reason.

Can anyone see a problem which I'm not spotting.

Comment: When more than one CASE is true it will return the first one

Comment: I did notice that if I place the last line at the top it then worked, but thought I was missing something else.  So to get this correct, even though the last when statement has an additional value to check SQL Server ignores that?

Comment: It stops with the first true condition,yes.

Answer (score 4):

For most cases

> The CASE statement evaluates its conditions sequentially and stops
>   with the first condition whose condition is satisfied

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: [No, this is not always true](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12941/does-sql-server-read-all-of-a-coalesce-function-even-if-the-first-argument-is-no/12945#12945).

Answer (score 1):

ReturnValue3 is a subset of ReturnValue2, therefore you need to check ReturnValue3 first, otherwise all combinations that would satisfy ReturnValue3 will be assigned to ReturnValue2.

```
DECLARE @Val1 int, @Val2 int,@Val3 int, @Val4 int, @Val5 int

SELECT  @Val1 = 5 , @Val2= 2,@Val3= 200000, @Val5  = 2,@Val4 = 2014
SELECT  @Val1 , @Val2,@Val3, @Val4, @Val5   

SELECT CASE
        WHEN  @Val1 = 5 AND @Val2  IN(1,2) AND @Val3 = 200000 AND @Val4 IS NULL  
         THEN 'ReturnValue1'
        WHEN  @Val1 = 5 AND @Val2  = 2 AND @Val3 = 200000  AND @Val5 = 2 AND @Val4 IS NOT NULL 
         THEN 'ReturnValue3'
        WHEN  @Val1 = 5 AND @Val2  IN(1,2) AND @Val3 = 200000 AND @Val4 IS NOT NULL 
         THEN 'ReturnValue2'
        ELSE NULL
    END [TestingValue]
```